# how can I do for my json return properly?

Tags: php, codeigniter

this function is for check modules what the user has permission,but when I used what this function return me like json dont show up all modules. it just show me up the last one.

controller

```
public function getModules($module_id){
     if ($this->session->userdata('log')){
         $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
         $menu = array();
         $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
         foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion) {
             $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
             //assuming you get 1 row only from the above query
             if (!empty($modules)) {
                    $modules['index'] = $index;
                    $menu['seccions'] = $modules;
             }
         }
         foreach ($seccions as $item) {
             array_push($menu,$item);
         }
         $this->json($menu);
         $this->load->view('modules_view',$menu);
     }
 }
```

model

```
public function get_rows(){
        $this->db->select('id,seccion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_seccion');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }

    public function query($query){
        return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    }
```

view html

```
<div class="row">
<h3 class="text-center">Welcome to storeLTE, click a module below to get started!</h3>
<div class="home_module_list">
    <div class="module_item">
        <?php foreach ($seccions as $session) { ?>
          <div class="module_item" title="<?= $session['value'];?>">
            <a href="<?= $session['url']; ?>"><img src="<?= $session['icon']; ?>"/></a>
            <a href="<?= $session['url']; ?>"><?= $session['value']?></a>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

my controller returns me this json

```
{"seccions":{"0":{"id":"22","icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png","value":"Compras","seccion_id":"2","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/compras\/compras"},"index":1}}
```

I would like to return it like this one:

```
[{"id":"1","seccion":"Inventario","data":[{"id":"11","icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/items.png","value":"Productos","seccion_id":"1","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/inventario\/product"},{"id":"14","icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/employees.png","value":"Provedores","seccion_id":"1","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/provedor\/provedor"}]},{"id":"2","seccion":"Compras","data":[{"id":"22","icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png","value":"Compras","seccion_id":"2","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/compras\/compras"}]}]
```

Comment: If you are fetching only one record then use row_array() instead of result_array().

Comment: im not fetching only one record